# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-scroll-horizontal'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, react-scroll

this error is showing -

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: landing_page@0.1.0

npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-scroll-horizontal@1.6.6

npm ERR! node_modules/react-scroll-horizontal

npm ERR!   react-scroll-horizontal@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR!

npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\rajneesh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-06T10_34_17_301Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rajneesh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-06T10_34_17_301Z-debug-0.log

This is my Dependencies which is currently I am working

"dependencies": {

```
"@types/node": "20.3.2",

"@types/react": "18.2.14",

"@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",

"autoprefixer": "10.4.14",

"bootstrap": "^5.3.0",

"eslint": "8.43.0",

"eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",

"next": "13.4.7",

"postcss": "8.4.24",

"react": "18.2.0",


"react-dom": "18.2.0",

"react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",

"tailwindcss": "3.3.2",


"typescript": "5.1.6"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have `node_modules` folder yet.

write in terminal `npm install` and hit enter

Comment: But I have node_module

Comment: can you share image of your folder structure?